# trasform-origin and scale in javascript

Tags: javascript

i need to replace this **CSS** code:

```
transform:scale(0,0);
transform-origin: top left;
```

with javascript code, but i don't know how to do.

i'm looking for something like this:

```
.style.opacity="0";
```

thanks

---

i've something like this:

```
x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.opacity="0";
x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.transform = "scale(0,0)";
x.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.transformOrigin = "0 0";
```

1 is ok, 2 & 3 don't work. (Chrome, IE)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
document.getElementById("your_elements_id").style.transform = 'scale(0,0)';
document.getElementById("your_elements_id").style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
```